# How would one send an HTTP POST request?

Tags: http, lua

I'm using lua-http for HTTP requests in my Lua script. I'm trying to find a way to send data as a POST request, similar to the -d option of `curl`.

I've tried `new_from_uri:set_body()` but I don't think I'm doing it correctly.

```lua
request = require "http.request"
headers, stream = assert(request.new_from_uri("https://example.org"):set_body("body text"))
headers, stream = assert(request.new_from_uri("https://example.org"):go())

body = assert(stream:get_body_as_string())
if headers:get ":status" ~= "200" then
    error(body)
end
```

Could someone show me how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use luasocket for this instead. Here is the code I'm using:

```lua
http = require "socket.http"
body = "body text"
respbody = {
result, respcode, respheaders, respstatus = http.request {
    method = "POST",
    url = "https://example.org",
    source = ltn12.source.string(body),
    headers = {
        ["content-type"] = "application/json", -- change if you're not sending JSON
        ["content-length"] = tostring(#body)
    },
    sink = ltn12.sink.table(respbody)
}
respbody = table.concat(respbody)
```